# How to get field id dynamically in js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In view I have contact form as:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
               <ul>
                  <li>                    
<?php echo $this->Form>input('Name',array('id'=>'name','class'=>'default'));?>
                  </li>
                  <li>                    
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Address',array('id'=>'address','class'=>'default'));?>
                  </li>
                  <li>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('Email',array('id'=>'email','class'=>'default'));?>
                  </li>
                  <li>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('Phone',array('id'=>'phone','class'=>'default'));?>
                  </li>
                  <li>

<?php echo $this->Form->textarea('Enquiry',array('id'=>'enquiry','class'=>'default'));?>
                  </li>

                </ul>
             <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

In js file i have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.default').blur(function(){

        $.post( 
        '/cakephp/Packages/validate_form',
        {field:$(this).attr('id'),value:$(this).val()
        },
            handleNameValidation
    );
});

function handleNameValidation(error){


    if(error.length>0){

        if($('#name-notEmpty').length==0){
            $('#name').after('<div id="name-notEmpty" class="error-message">'+ error + "</div>");
        }
    }
    else{
        $('.error-message').remove();
    }
}
});
```

Here I got the error message dynamically but i am unable get field id dynamically in:

```
$('#name').after('<div id="name-notEmpty" class="error-message">'+ error + "</div>");
```

field.Here i define field id as `#name` as static but want this field dynamically .Any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have solve this problem as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.default').blur(function(){
        var self = this;
        $.post( 
                '/cakephp/Packages/validate_form',
                {field:$(this).attr('id'),value:$(this).val()
                },
                function(error){

                    handleNameValidation(error,self)

                }
            );
            function handleNameValidation(error,el){
                 var $parent = $(el).parent();
                    if(error.length>0){
                            if($('span.error-message',$parent).length==0){
                            $parent.append('<span class="error-message">'+ error + '</span>');
                            }
                            else{
                                 $('span.error-message',$parent).replaceWith('<span class="error-message">'+ error + '</span>');
                            }
                    }
                    else{
                         $parent.removeClass('error-message');
                         $('span.error-message',$parent).fadeOut();
                    }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code but its not tested. Try once

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.default').blur(function(){
     var fieldID=$(this).attr('id');
     $.post( 
      '/cakephp/Packages/validate_form',
      {field:fieldID,value:$(this).val()
      },
        handleNameValidation(error,fieldID);
    );
  });

  function handleNameValidation(error,fieldID){
     if(error.length>0){

       if($('#name-notEmpty').length==0){
         $('#'+fieldID).after('<div id="name-notEmpty" class="error-message">'+ error + "   </div>");
       }
    }
    else{
      $('.error-message').remove();
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier but it doesn't work.Unable to get fieldId value inside function